# How to create a function with infinite slope at a specific (x,y) location, in addition to a horizontal asymptote?

Tags: limits, asymptotics

I'm trying to code a rocket launch gravity turn, and I'm reminded of how long it's been since I've taken a math course. I've tried with inverse quadratic functions and log functions, but I can't get things to line up quite right. Here's the parameters I'm looking for:

\begin{Bmatrix}
 y/x=\infty, & when(x=0, y<10,000)\\
 0<y<10,000, & when(x=0) \\
 \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0+}(y/x)=\infty,& when(x>0)\\
 \displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty }f(x)=80,000 \\
\end{Bmatrix}

[And here's what I've got so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3P2NB.jpg). Basically trying to get the start of the blue with the end of the red. I'm tempted to just translate stuff around until I've got something passable, but I'm sure there's a better way to do this. And ideally, I'd be able to set the limits as arguments in my code without throwing everything off. Any pointers to get me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: You could start with $\,\sqrt{\frac{x}{x+1}}\,$ and shift/scale as needed.

Comment: @dxiv That's actually great! Almost exactly what I was looking for, thanks!